# How do I export HTML to PDF using telerik.pdf namespace

Tags: html, pdf, telerik, pdf-generation, pdf-writer

I have the requirement where on *click* of a button, I want to write the contents on multiple lists to PDF document
For example, I have List and I want to write all the details present in Employee class to the *pdf* document
I want to implement this export to pdf functionality using `telerik.pdf` as this is the only third-party assembly allowed in my project.